# LNK2001 error when building in Release-DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, release, activemq-cpp

I am making some changes in Apache ActiveMQ CMS library (a potential bug fix). I have fixed the bug and tested it in Debug mode. Now I want to make it's release dll to be added in my project. When I try to build using Release-DLL configuration, Following error comes up:

```
DiscoveryTransport.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall activemq::util::Suspendable::~Suspendable(void)" (??1Suspendable@util@activemq@@UAE@XZ)
```

.lib and .exp files are being created successfully. Please note following findings:

- It compiles fine in Debug (static lib) and Release (static lib) configurations

Please consider following configurations:

- Platform Toolset : `visual studio 2008 (v90)` [Required for my build]
- Configuration Type: `Dynamic Library (.dll)`
- Whole Program optimization: `Use Link Time Code Generation` *tried `No Whole Program Optimization` with no luck
- Character Set: `Not Set` *as per in Debug and Release Configuration
- C/C++ >> General >> Debug Information Format: `Program Database (/Zi)`
- C/C++ >> Optimization: `Maximize Speed (/O2)`
- C/C++ >> Code Generation >> Run-time Library: `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` *Tried with (/MDd) but no luck
- C/C++ >> Precompiled Headers: `Not using precompiled headers`
- C/C++ >> Advanced >> Calling Convention: `__cdecl (/Gd)`
- Linker >> Input: Added `libapr-1.lib` as it has dependency upon Apache Runtime
- Linker >> Debugging >> Generate Debug Info: `Yes (/DEBUG)`
- Linker >> System >> SubSystem: `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`
- Linker >> Advanced >> Target Machine: `MachineX86 (/MACHINE:X86)`
- Linker >> Advanced >> Error Reporting: `PromptImmediately (/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT)`
- Paths to include and lib are correct as being used in Debug and Release Configurations
- I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition

The code I changed has nothing to do with `DiscoveryTransport` class. I have been trying it since two days. Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You have probably forgot to add a library to the release build settings

Comment: Library include and lib paths are added and I have counter checked them. Library name added in Linker -> Input ->Additional Libraries for Release-DLL build. I have mentioned it in question as well.

Comment: Did you clean the solution before building? Probably not it, but worth a try.

Comment: Yes I did clean - rebuild the project although. Did a clean again followed by rebuild after your comment, yielding same error.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can make a copy of the debug configuration and switch optimizations on, to see if it works.

Comment: Just now I found something amazing. [ActiveMQ CMS Download Page](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/activemq-cpp-393-release.html) lists Source distribution and git clone url. I cloned git url. This git clone include src/main/activemq/transport/DiscoveryTransport/ but sources given on same page doesn't include discovery transport in src/main/activemq/tranposrt/. Both are same version i.e. 3.9.3. I am getting error exactly in DiscoveryTransport.obj where ~Suspendable(void){} is accessed. Going to raise issue in community.